# postgres/nextcloud keeps drives active

Tags: postgresql, nextcloud, hd-idle

I run a small home server with Debian including a autoshutdown script if the system is idle. Since a few days my drives are not staying in standby and with this the server is always running.

I analysed this with `iotop -bktoqqq -d .5` and the following entry always shows up when the drives are going back from `standby` to `active`

```
rsyslogd -n -iNONE [rs:main Q:Reg]
postgres: 11/main: nextcloud_db_user nextcloud_db ::1(42284) idle
```

or

```
rsyslogd -n -iNONE [rs:main Q:Reg]
postgres: 11/main: nextcloud_db_user nextcloud_db ::1(34282) UPDATE
postgres: 11/main: nextcloud_db_user nextcloud_db ::1(34282) SELECT
```

What could be the reason for these? My postgres database is not located on these 2 hard drives. Only data is.

Additional problem is that I have same or similar entries in my log as well where drives are staying in standby.